# how can i confirm that the retry is working in spring batch impelmentation

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I got spring batch inplace and i want to configure a retry logic i got the following configuration:

```
<step id="roundUpMonthlyJobFetchUsers">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="roundUpMonthlyItemReader" processor="roundUpMonthlyItemProcessor"
                       writer="roundUpMonthlyItemWriter" commit-interval="1" retry-limit="3" >
                    <retryable-exception-classes>
                        <include class="java.io.IOException" />
                    </retryable-exception-classes>
               </chunk>
            </tasklet>
         <end on="COMPLETED"/>
    <fail on="FAILED"/>
</step>
```

How can cofirm that this its actually trying to do the operation for atleast 3 times when it encounters the IOException

Answer (score 0):

Change this class `roundUpMonthlyItemReader`

To log something on entry and then throw the IOException everytime, then check the logs :)

```
log.info("Reading Monthly round up");
throw new IOException("Dummy IOException");
```

If you wish to do this in your unit tests, you should be able to use Mockito to

- Mock the reader or writer to throw IOException
- Ensure it is called 3 times

Comment: I tried that already, but when i throw exception it comes up in logs only ones not three times. I dont know if I need to implement the retrytemplate and put the logic in there which i want to run in retry, it does not make sense because off course i want to run the same step but just confused because i logs I only see this exception once either with retry or without retry :S

Comment: and its roundUpMonthlyItemProcessor where I want it to retry.